# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcionen mis radio botones y checkboxes al hacerles click?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Este es mi código (ver completo en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CeciPeque/pen/axYRLr?editors=1100#0)):

```css
html {
  background: #bbb;
}

.radio-buttons, .checkboxes {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 400px;
}

.radio-buttons li {
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.checkboxes li {
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.radio-buttons li input[type='radio'], .checkboxes li input[type='checkbox']{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-buttons li label, .checkboxes li label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.radio-buttons li:hover label, .checkboxes li:hover label{
 color: #FFF;
}

.radio-buttons li .check, .checkboxes li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
 z-index: 5;
 transition: border .25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

.radio-buttons li:hover .check, .checkboxes li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.radio-buttons li .check::before, .checkboxes li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
 content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
 transition: background 0.25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type='radio']:checked ~ .check, input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .check{
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.checkboxes ul {
  height: 350px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label>What region do you prefer?</label><br><br>
      <ul class="radio-buttons">
        <li>
          <label for="region">Kanto</label><input type="radio" id="region" name="region" value="kanto">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
        <li>
          <label for="region">Joto</label><input type="radio" id="region" name="region" value="joto">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
      <li>
          <label for="region">Hoen</label><input type="radio" id="region" name="region" value="hoen">
        <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Funciona el hover y todo pero la propiedad `:checked` de `input[type='radio']:checked` y `input[type='checkbox']:checked` no me está funcionando como debería. En el caso de los radio botones al hacer click me deja marcar solo uno y en el caso de los checkboxes no importa cual apriete siempre se marca el primero de arriba.

También estoy teniendo problemas con el hover del submit input, no pasa a ninguna transición cuando el mouse pasa por encima de él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que todos tus radio botones tienen el mismo ID y todos los label apuntan al mismo ID. Debes hacer que los radio botones tengan IDs diferentes y que los label apunten al ID del radio button correspondiente. El `name` se mantiene igual para todos y de ese modo te aseguras que sólo uno podrá marcarse y será enviado al servidor con el formulario.

En el código que has compartido, he cambiado los IDs para añadirles un número y los label ahora apuntan al ID que deben:

```css
html {
  background: #bbb;
}

.radio-buttons, .checkboxes {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 400px;
}

.radio-buttons li {
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.checkboxes li {
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.radio-buttons li input[type='radio'], .checkboxes li input[type='checkbox']{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-buttons li label, .checkboxes li label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.radio-buttons li:hover label, .checkboxes li:hover label{
 color: #FFF;
}

.radio-buttons li .check, .checkboxes li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
 z-index: 5;
 transition: border .25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

.radio-buttons li:hover .check, .checkboxes li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.radio-buttons li .check::before, .checkboxes li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
 content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
 transition: background 0.25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type='radio']:checked ~ .check, input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .check{
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.checkboxes ul {
  height: 350px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label>What region do you prefer?</label><br><br>
      <ul class="radio-buttons">
        <li>
          <label for="region-1">Kanto</label><input type="radio" id="region-1" name="region" value="kanto">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
        <li>
          <label for="region-2">Joto</label><input type="radio" id="region-2" name="region" value="joto">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
      <li>
          <label for="region-3">Hoen</label><input type="radio" id="region-3" name="region" value="hoen">
        <div class="check"></div>
        </li><br>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Otra opción que podrías hacer es eliminar los IDs y hacer que el `label` englobe todo dentro del `li` (el texto del label, el checkbox, y el check). Al estar el `input` dentro del `label` se marcará automáticamente sin necesidad de especificar ID en el `for`.

Comment: Si tienes razon, se me paso, pero que tonta soy, muchas gracias.